# CVS and SVN Tagging

Tags: svn, cvs

In CVS, it is possible to tag a version whenever there is release, but in SVN, we can do it only by creating a repository. Any queries on this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally in SVN you would create a branch for a new version or feature. Work would be done there and then integrated back into the trunk when it's ready for release. Then you would make a copy of that specific release as a tag. Some teams use branches as stable areas, some use the trunk.  It really depends on how you want to do it and how you like to manage branches. But you usually wouldn't create a new repo.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the query!! prod

Answer (score 2):

Typically in SVN you should create a Branch of a given repository, and tag it as a version, not a whole new repository.

Comment: @Dinzy: "query" means "question", not "answer".